# typeof function is not a function

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Colleague showed me the next code, which blown my mind:

```js
const x = Object.create(function() {});
// variant: const x = Object.create(Array);
console.log(x.call) // ƒ call() { [native code] }
console.log(typeof x.call) // "function"
console.log(x.call instanceof Function) // true
x.call() // Uncaught TypeError: x.call is not a function
```

I understand that `x.call` is prototyped from `function`, it's not own `x`'s property:

```
x.hasOwnProperty('call') // false
```

But why `x.call` can't actually being executed? Is it something related to [call keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)?

Comment: Sometimes more exact error messages are useful, FF says: "_TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible Object_"

Comment: Note that `x` has no function body.   You can't call a function that doesn't have one.

Comment: Also note that passing an _instance_ of a type to `Object.create` doesn't produce the same result as passing the _prototype_ of that type.  You usually want to do the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core idea behind Object.create boils down to this:

```
function create(prt){
    var noOP = function(){};
    noOP.prototype = prt;
    return new noOP;
}
```

So, the returned value is NOT a function, it is an object. To illustrate, I'll first store a function:

```
var u = function(){return 5}
```

Now I'll use `Object.create` on it:

```
var res = create(u);
```

Consoling it will give you `>noOP {}`, so it is a plain object. The problem starts from here:

```
res.hasOwnProperty("prototype") //false
```

So the newly created object has "prototype" but this is in fact inherited from `u`:

```
res.prototype === u.prototype //true
```

Similary, "call" is again inherited from u which in turn u inherits from its constructor's (Function) prototype:

```
res.call === u.call //true
res.call === Function.prototype.call //also true
```

And here is your problem, if you look at the EcmaScript implementation of `call`, it expects a `this` and `this` should be callable. Isolate `call` from `res` :

```
var x = res.call; //ƒ call() { [native code] }
```

Now I will "call" the call, we will pass 3 arguments, 1st for what to call, 2nd for setting `this` inside that callable, 3rd and so forth for arguments for the callable:

```
x.call(function(a){console.log("hey");console.log(a);console.log(this);},5,5)
//hey
//5
//Number {5}
```

Now try the same on your created object `res` either by `res.call` or `x.call`:

```
x.call(res,5,5) //TypeError: x.call is not a function
```

In the end, it boils down to returned object from `Object.create` not being callable.

Answer (score 3):

Cause `x` is an object that inherits `call` from `Function.prototype`, however `call` is meant to be called on a function, therefore it fails if you try to execute it on a plain object.

Comment: On Chrome `Function.prototype.call()` returns `undefined` and doesn't produce an error.

Comment: @alnitak oops, seems like `Function.prototype()` is a function itself...